# How to set the identifier of an NSTabViewItem?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstabview

I want to know when a `NSTabView` switched to a particular view. For that I've extended `NSTabViewController` with my custom class to be able to act as delegate:

```
class OptionsTabViewController: NSTabViewController {
    override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
        print(tabViewItem!.identifier)
    }
}
```

This prints what looks like pointer memory positions:

```
Optional(0x608000100e10)
Optional(0x6080000c36b0)
```

I imagine it should be possible to set those identifiers somewhere in interface builder, but I've tried writing stuff in different text fields labeled as `identifier` and still get those memory position values in the console.

I've also used `print(tabViewItem!.label)` but it prints the label in the tab button.

So how can I set that identifier to be able to recognise which view is active in the tab view component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you may define your identifier(s) in this way:

[image]

then in your code you might define an `enum` for checking which is the current selected tab, doing something like:

```
enum YourTabs:String {
   case tab1
   case tab2
   case none
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTabViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tabView:NSTabView!

    public func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
        if let identifier = tabViewItem?.identifier as? String,
            let currentTab = YourTabs(rawValue: identifier) {
            switch currentTab {
            case .tab1:
                print("do something with tab1")
                break
            case .tab2:
                print("do something with tab2")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameter `tabViewItem` is the tab view item that was selected. Use `tabViewItem` instead of `tabView.selectedTabViewItem`.

Comment: Thanks. The image you posted is in the attributes inspector which I completely missed since I was looking at the identity inspector.